# Get value of input type text by using Name instead of Id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

For a `<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">`, it is possible to use `document.getElementbyId('vegs').value` to get the input of the text box. 
But is there a way to get input by using the `name` attribute of the `<input>`tag?

`document.getElementsbyName('fruits').value` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: document.getElementsByName('fruits')[0].value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (which is like an array), so you need to select the first item.

There could be multiple inputs with name of fruits. If that is the case, iterate over the NodeList just like you would iterate over an array.

I made a snippet for you:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(document.getElementsByName("fruits")[0].value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

If you want to use multiple inputs with the same name, you can use the snippet below.

This uses a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to iterate over the fruits array (I know its a NodeList, but think of it as an array. It has very similar features and will make life much easier this way).

```js
var fruits;

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  fruits = document.getElementsByName("fruits"); //fruits is now a NodeList
  fruits.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">
<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">
<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">
<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: @MegCullen no problem. With DOM, if the `.getElements` is plural, it returns a NodeList. Otherwise, it returns a single item

Comment: So that means we can have multiple tags with same name and call the value as required using [#]...is that right?

Comment: @MegCullen Right. I'll make a snippet for you in my answer demonstrating that right now

Comment: @MegCullen ok I updated my answer. Look at the second snippet.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm always glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189349/discussion-between-aniket-g-and-meg-cullen).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
function show_value() {
  var ret = document.querySelector("input[name='fruits']").value;
  console.log(ret);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="vegs" name="fruits">
<button onclick="show_value()">Click</button>
```

Be **careful with IE10 and below** behavior when using [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName#Notes).

> The getElementsByName method works differently in IE10 and below. There, getElementsByName() also returns elements that have an id attribute with the specified value. Be careful not to use the same string as both a name and an id.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

> **getElementsByName()**: method of the Document object **returns a NodeList Collection of elements** with a given name in the document

You can access the first element using `[0]`

```js
function change(){
  console.log(document.getElementsByName('fruits')[0].value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="change()" id="vegs" name="fruits">
```

Comment: @Meg Cullen accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

this will do ..

```
   document.getElementsByName("fruits")[0].value
```

getElementsByName returns array of elements having name= fruits
.
[0] returns the first element which in your case is the only element having name=fruits..

Comment: Thank you so much.